# Aritchie text truncated for Toast messages on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have installed Aritchie userdialogs version 5 and I'm using Xamarin.Forms Version 2.2. When I use UserDialogs.Instance.ErrorToast on Android, if the text is longer than screen width, it cut.
This is a problem cause the user might not see important part of a message.
(Same toast message on iOS for example not truncated and it takes the size of the content automatically).

How can I increase the height of this rectangle, or set an autosize if exist ?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

When your Android app is running with a `AppCompatActivity` based `Activity` (which it seems that your is since it is using Material Design), Acr UserDialogs is creating a `SnackBar` for displaying the Toast, and by design a Google/Android `SnackBar` is supposed to be a short message.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html

> Snackbars provide lightweight feedback about an operation by showing a brief message at the bottom of the screen

As such there is not built-in method for auto-sizing or multi-line wrapping of text. There are other SO questions related to this and their answers all point to the thing, you would need to modify the Android-based view that is contained within the Snackbar fragment when it is created:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.SnackbarText);
// change the font size, view size, content wrap settings, etc...
```

If these are important messages that the user needs to dismiss, perhaps using a popup dialog would work in your design.

Comment: I create this page in PCL, do you know where I have to place your line of code inside Android project ? Maybe a custom render of the entire ContentPage ?

Comment: @Stefano You either could skip using Acr UserDialogs and create your own Toast control using a custom Xamarin.Forms render, or do it via a dependancy service (make be easier/quicker this way) or modify the Acr UserDialog source, see the `ToastAppCompat` method @ https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/7e7a42a3e87a32701f071768552bc8622981bab1/src/Acr.UserDialogs.Android/UserDialogsImpl.cs

Comment: I would like to go for the easier/quicker way, unfortunatly I have no idea how to implement this dependency service as I'm pretty new on this. I have implemented a dependency service for storing file on device and for storing a database locally. I don't know how to use a dependency service for showing up this toast and change its attributes :(
May you explain me or point me on a sample somewhere ?